# Trying to automate the download of images from psacard.com but running into PerimeterX issues

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate the download of images from psacard.com - namely the images of graded collectable cards that I have sent off to them.

The images are available on the card's certification page - one such example is https://www.psacard.com/cert/68786145/psa   .

The use case for this code is to quickly and efficiently download all the images for the cert numbers of my cards, so that I may use them in my online marketplace stores. Currently this process has to be done manually and is very laborious.

I have managed to write code that downloads the images for one card given a user-inputted cert number, but when I expanded my program to iterate through a list of cert numbers I started running into PerimeterX capatchas and blocks. I am still able to manually access the pages in the same browser window.

Here is the code I have written:

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
import random
import requests
certstart= input("Please type the first cert number")
certend= input("Please type in the last cert number")

certs =[]
for i in range(int(certstart), int(certend) + 1):
    certs.append(i)
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\danie\\.cache\\selenium\\chromedriver\\win32\\109.0.5414.74\\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.psacard.com"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

for cert in certs:
    
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    url = "https://www.psacard.com/cert/" + str(cert) 
    driver.get(url)
    html_doc = driver.page_source
    print(html_doc)
    time.sleep(2+random.randint(1,4))
    orig_text = html_doc

    first_separator = 'id="psaCertImages"'
    

    output = []

    orig_text = orig_text.split(" ")
    print (first_separator in orig_text)
    
    if first_separator in orig_text:
        output = orig_text[orig_text.index(first_separator)+1 : ]
        
     
    imgs = []
    for i in output:
        if "cloudfront" in i:
            if "href" in i:
                url = i.strip("href=")
                url = url.strip('"')
                imgs.append(url)

    print(imgs)
    count = 0
    text = ["front", "back"]
    for i in imgs:
        s = requests.session()
        r = s.get(i, allow_redirects=True)
        open(str(cert) + "-" + text[count] + '.jpeg', 'wb').write(r.content)
        count += 1
        time.sleep(2+random.randint(1,4))
    time.sleep(10 + random.randint(1,10))
`
```

A list of sample cert numbers to try is [68786145,68786146,68786147,68786148].

The first time the code is run, the cert number page loads fine. However, the second attempt invariably fails.

I am using my computer at the time of using the script so mouse/keyboard movement is natural and shouldn't flag up as a bot.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong will be gratefully received!

Comment: did you try those browser extensions which let you download all images from a webpage?

Comment: I haven't but there's only 2 pictures I want to download from each page (the front and back of the card), and a few pictures I don't want to download.

Basically I need to automate the opening of x number of pages and the downloading of the front and back of card images from each of those pages.

Comment: I played a bit with different browsers but all get blocked after few pages loaded, I also tried with undetected selenium but same happened. Moreover, I'm not able to solve the captcha even if I try manually  I suggest you to open an issue on undetected selenium github repository and ask for help https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues. Also, take a look here, where an user said he was able to solve the captcha by adding human mimicking stuff https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/720

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'll get on those and will report back with any findings.